# file upload using flash button(*.swf) in Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, flash, button, selenium-webdriver, uploading

in my test web page I have to upload a file, the uploader is a flash based (*.swf) button. Can someone give me the proper code to test the file upload button?

driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/object")).click();

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to handle flash objects using selenium webdriver. You can use 3rd party API like Sikuli for this.

Please check the following post on [Sikuli integration with selenium webdriver Example](http://testingtoolstecniques.blogspot.in/2015/04/using-sikuli-api-with-selenium-web.html)